# How to run unit tests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using **swift 5.1** and **XCTestCase** framework, however Xcode fails to recognize that I have unit tests. Is there something I'm missing? All of the documentation on Apple shows that I am doing things correctly.

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of code, please. "All of the documentation on Apple shows that I am doing things correctly." No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions have to have the prefix 'test'. In your case it would be `func testTrueWhenPassIsEmpty` for example.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/defining_test_cases_and_test_methods) and a good starter tutorial is here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/39/2/creating-our-first-unit-test-using-xctest

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that part of the documentation.

Comment: @TrejonHouse would be great if you can mark the answer as correct, so others can see it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Each test function has to have the **'test'** word in front function name. So Xcode can recognize that this function is a test.

For example in your case it should be :

```swift
testReturnsTrueWhenPassInNil() { ... }
```

instead of:

```swift
returnsTrueWhenPassInNil() { ... }
```